# Regex Pattern of Color hex

Tags: java, regex

i have a `String` like this , I want to replace '`color:#*****;`' with `null` , i had try to use all possible pattern, Please help me

```
String s="<p style='color: rgb(87, 112, 131);'><span style='color:#daa520;'><u>Need alliance match fo</u>r Pune based Gupta Boy <em>27/5'6''. MBA - Runs own </em>business. Girl</span> <span style='color:#00ffff;'>should be well educated</span> <span style='font-size:14pt;'>homely, slim, tall &amp; b/ful. </span>Caste no bar</p>";
```

Comment: Why would you want to replace `style='color:#daa520;'` with `style='null;'`? And no, we won't "hell" you. This is not a demonic site.

Comment: actually i have to convert pdf color into BW so  style='' , means BW color , I am be beginner please help me Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a replace all :

```
s = s.replaceAll("color:#[0-9a-fA-F]{6};", "null");
```

Comment: Thanx Xephi  ialso found one more solution

Comment: one more solution i found
 s = s.replaceAll("color:[^;]*;", "");